# How to display images from Photo gallery on uiwebview ios swift?

Tags: ios, uiwebview, swift2

Using Photos API(PHImageManager) i am able to get list of photos url and photo object.
When I am trying to use that url in webview , image is not displaying

Consider the following image url which I got from Photos API(PHImageManager)

Comment: can you show me code for webview?...

Comment: in this place use collectionView or tableview ,

Comment: @HiteshSurani, I am directly using url got from Photos API like  "file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0315.JPG", Pls Let me know will this work ?

Comment: not work bcoz you need to separate this file:///var/mobile/Media/DCIM/100APPLE/IMG_0315.JPG string then find photo name and  search in photo and then display in to webView or imageView

Answer (score 0):

you just have to take that burl in string and then load that string in webview in viewdidload

like

urlStr = obj["url"] as! String

and then load that url in uiwebview

webview.loadRequest(NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: urlStr)!))